# nx adds dist/packages to my paths mappings

Tags: tsconfig, nrwl-nx

**Question:** Why does TypeScript/Nx add `dist/packages` to my path mappings?

I'm converting my polyrepo project to nx monorepo. In my polyrepo, I have a repo `mpg-common`  with `src` folder, and all other repos import from it: `import { Bla } from 'mpg-common/lib/services/...`. I want to preserve this import syntax when moving to monorepo, so in `tsconfig.base.json` I put `compilerOptions: { "paths": { "mpg-common/lib/*": ["packages/mpg-common/src/*"]`

However, these imports fail. To debug I set `"traceResolution": true`, and then I see:

```
Module name 'mpg-common/lib/inversify.config', matched pattern 'mpg-common/lib/*'.
Trying substitution 'dist/packages/mpg-common/lib/*', candidate module location: 'dist/packages/mpg-common/lib/inversify.config'.
```

So, question: Why does TypeScript/Nx add these `dist/packages` to my path mappings?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my `package.json` had `"name": "mpg-common"`, which caused nx to auto-map `mpg-common => dist/packages/mpg-common`, which is taken from `packages/mpg-common/project.json => targets/build/options/outputPath`.

So, solution: change in package.json to `"name": "@myworkspace/mpg-common"`